# BASH–Getting results from PHP

Tags: php, bash, string-interpolation

I am trying to retrieve some output from php, using bash. So far I have this:

```
CODE="<?php chdir('$WWW');" # $WWW should be interpolated

CODE+=$(cat <<'PHP' # no interpolation for the rest of the code
    require_once('./settings.php'); 

    $db = $databases['default']['default'];

    $out = [
        'user=' . $db['username']
        //more here
    ];

    echo implode("\n", $out)
PHP)

echo $CODE    

#RESULT=$($CODE | php)

#. $RESULT
```

All in all I am having trouble with the String interpolation. Right now I get:

```
line 10: <?php: command not found
```

So how can I properly escape the string such that the whole php code?

All in all, the PHP should generate output like that:

```
key=value
key2=value2
```

which can be "sourced" by the bash

Thanks in Ahead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using [Here String](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html)**

```
php <<< "$CODE"
```

**Using Pipe**

```
echo "$CODE" | php
```

If you want to store the output into a variable, use the [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect_03_04_04):

```
result=$(php <<< "$CODE")
result=$(echo "$CODE" | php)
```

Comment: This is the more complete answer, so I will choose that one!

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong: `RESULT=$($CODE | php)` - shell variable can't be passed like that, it attempts to run `$CODE` as a command.

Instead you can do `RESULT=$(echo "$CODE" | php)` or `RESULT=$(php <<<"$CODE")`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 errors in here:

1. error in your here-doc block. No need for `'` around PHP.
2. You need to escape the `$` in your PHP code, or otherwise it will be expanded by bash.

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash

CODE="<?php chdir('$WWW');" # $WWW should be interpolated

CODE+=$(cat << PHP # no interpolation for the rest of the code
    //require_once('./settings.php'); 

    \$db = "foo";

    \$out = [
        'user=' . \$db
        //more here
    ];

    echo implode("\n", \$out)
PHP
)

echo $CODE
```

This will print out:

```
<?php chdir("/tmp"); //require_once('./settings.php'); $db = "foo"; $out = [ 'user=' . $db //more here ]; echo implode("\n", $out);
```

Which can be evaluated in php.

Comment: Having `'` around PHP in the Heredoc statement is a good thing. It means that the content won't be subjected to expansion of special characters - therefore there will be no need to add backslashes before `$`.

Comment: Thanks for that info. I wasn't aware of that. One never stops learning.